# Problems when integrating Mapbox in new layout/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, mapbox

Recently I changed layout for a website, on some pages I used the mapbox api. Since the switch of stylesheet the mapbox looks all messed up with wrong ratio and white lines running accros the map.

Here's a picture of before and after:

[Before, how it should look like]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uplb.jpg

[After, how it should not look like]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZWKz.jpg

Been looking through the css and googling to see which parameters would interfere or have anything to do with messing up the map but without any succes. If anyone knows what I should edit would love to know!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

In order to receive help, you will need to post the code in question and describe what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map are made of tiles. Tiles are images. 
Your new style seems to add margin to images.

Try to add following line to your css

```
img.leaflet-tile { margin:0px }
```

Comment: As an addendum to that, check the css styles for `img` as well as `img.leaflet-tile`.  Your new style may be messing with the global img tag.